# How can I split my dictionary by the word 'by' and keep only the book name?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-science, data-analysis

Here is a sample of my dictionary:

```
{'Fiction Books 2019': ['The Testaments by Margaret Atwood',
'Normal People by Sally Rooney',
'Where the Forest Meets the Stars by Glendy Vanderah',
'Ask Again, Yes by Mary Beth Keane',
'Queenie by Candice Carty-Williams',
"On Earth We're Briefly Gorgeous by Ocean Vuong",
'A Woman Is No Man by Etaf Rum',
'The Overdue Life of Amy Byler by Kelly Harms'... etc }
```

How can I do to only keep the Name of the books?

I have tried the following but the loop adds all the books to every key in my dictionary:

```
books_name_dict = dict.fromkeys((col_names), [])

for k in books_name_dict:
    for i in range(len(nominee_list_dict_try[k])):
        books_name_dict[k].append(nominee_list_dict_try[k][i].split(' by ')[0])
```

Comment: `df['Fiction Books 2019'].str.split(" by ").str[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
books = {k: [x.split(" by ")[0] for x in v] for k, v in books.items()}
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/076057230a)

Comment: This works great - Thank you! Putting out a Demo is a great idea! ~~

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have supplied a single list instance `[]` in your call to `dict.fromkeys`. This is why you see everything in every list, it is actually just one list!

You should be able to fix by using `defaultdict` to make a new `list` for every key.

```py
import collections

books_name_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k in books_name_dict:
    for i in range(len(nominee_list_dict_try[k])):
        books_name_dict[k].append(nominee_list_dict_try[k][i].split(' by ')[0])
```

**Update**

As an aside, the iteration can be done a bit more directly.

```py
for k, v in books_name_dict.items():
    for title in v:
        books_name_dict[k].append(title.split(' by ')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you this works great as well! Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

```
books_name_dict = {'Fiction Books 2019': ['The Testaments by Margaret Atwood',
'Normal People by Sally Rooney',
'Where the Forest Meets the Stars by Glendy Vanderah',
'Ask Again, Yes by Mary Beth Keane',
'Queenie by Candice Carty-Williams',
"On Earth We're Briefly Gorgeous by Ocean Vuong",
'A Woman Is No Man by Etaf Rum',
'The Overdue Life of Amy Byler by Kelly Harms']} 

for k,v in books_name_dict.items():
    books_name_dict[k] = [b.split(" by ")[0] for b in v]
```